# How to draw lines connecting nearby points

Tags: plotting, fitting

Suppose I have the following example data,

```
data = Table[{Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/8}];
```

which, when plotted, looks like this,

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

[image]

Instead, imagine rather than being in order, the data order is scrambled,

```
data = RandomSample[data, Length@data];
```

Now, the plot looks not too pretty,

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to draw straight lines (not curves) connecting the points as in the top graph, using the scrambled data (when we do not know the true order)?

Comment: `FindShortestTour`?

Comment: Seems to work a treat -- thank you! Didn't know of that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [`ListCurvePathPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html):

```
ListCurvePathPlot[data, 
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][1], PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) and `ListLinePlot`:

```
ListLinePlot[data[[FindCurvePath[data][[1]]]], Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by That Gravity Guy, the following works,

```
ListLinePlot[data[[FindShortestTour[data][[2]]]], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}]
```

[image]