# Connecting simple lines from (large) unsorted list of points

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, interpolation

**Context**

[image]

We are trying to predict the formation of discs of intermediate mass black hole  orbiting super massive black holes in galactic centres.
This involves finding calorific curves in energy and angular momentum space.

**Problem**

I am trying to identify sets of curves from a (very large) sets of points in order to produce a lighter figure.

For instance I want to be able to redo such figure, but with less points (without loosing the poorly sampled lines).

[image]

The challenge is that these points are found by some complex optimisation routine
and are over-numerous in places. So by lighter figure, I mean remove sets of point very close to each other while keeping more sparsely sampled points in order to draw curves
through them.

**Question**

> How can one achieve this simultaneous downsampling and curve matching procedure?

---

**Attempt**

Let me define a toy problem as follows: let me produce two curves:

```
data = Flatten[{Table[{x, Sin[x^2/15]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.01}],
    Table[{x, 2 + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.1}]}, 1];
```

and draw random points from those.

```
pts = RandomChoice[data, Length[data]];

ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

Note that on purpose the sampling is not the same for the two curves.

---

I found on this site and in the documentation a couple of partial solutions to this problem, but none  does both the curve identification and downsampling properly.

The first method relies on `Nearest` (from the documentation) but does neither job (interpolation or downsampling) particularly well:

```
p = Nearest[pts];
pts1 = p[#, 2][[2]] & /@ pts;
Graphics[{Line[{##}] & @@@ Transpose[{pts, pts1}]}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 2/3]
```

[image]

From this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186738/1089) I tried also `ListCurvePathPlot` which seems like a good start
but does not down sample.

```
pl = ListCurvePathPlot[pts, Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][2], PointSize[Large]],
  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Finally `FindShortestTour` doesnt do as good a job, but lets me downsample by brute
force (which is clearly sub optimal).

---

```
ListLinePlot[pts[[FindShortestTour[pts][[2]][[;; ;; 20]]]], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]

---

I am optimistic that this question has a Mathematica answer since
it can be done by hand relatively easily (?)

Comment: I guess, the results of `FindShortestTour` should be post-processed with additional criteria. Jump from one fork to another is conjugated with significant change of the distance. So, you need go along the sorted points looking on the value of current distance and cut the array for segments. Further you can downsample them as you wish.

Comment: @Rom38 agreed; may be a mixture between Nearest and FindShortestTour? Or Interpolation? It would be best to find as generic a solution to this problem as possible.

Comment: In a sense, your example is "easy" as the two curves do not intersect. Intersection makes things much harder.

Comment: @A.G. Absolutely. I have added another question (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/250907/1089) to try and address this more general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to downsample based on the distance between points. I use `Manipulate` to adjust the threshold that reduces the number of points. As the $x$ and $y$ axes are on different scales it is probably better to scale before taking euclidean distances, as is done in the second example.

```
SeedRandom[0];
data = Flatten[{Table[{x, Sin[x^2/15]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.01}], 
    Table[{x, 2 + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.1}]}, 1];
n = Length[data];
pts = RandomChoice[data, n];

(* Eliminate points based on euclidean distance *)
Manipulate[
 p1 = DeleteDuplicates[pts, 
   EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] <= minDistance1 &];
 ListPlot[p1, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"Number of points: ", Length@p1, " out of ", n}]],
 {{minDistance1, .1}, 0, 0.25}]

(* Eliminate points based on scaled euclidean distance *)
xRange = With[{x = First /@ pts}, Max@x - Min@x];
yRange = With[{y = Last /@ pts}, Max@y - Min@y];
scaledDistance[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}] := 
  Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2/xRange^2 + (y2 - y1)^2/yRange^2 ];

Manipulate[
 p2 = DeleteDuplicates[pts, 
   scaledDistance[#1, #2] <= minDistance2 &];
 ListPlot[p2, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"Number of points: ", Length@p2, " out of ", n}]],
 {{minDistance2, .02}, 0.01, 0.05}]

(* Now add interpolation *)
Manipulate[
 p3 = DeleteDuplicates[pts, 
   scaledDistance[#1, #2] <= minDistance3 &];
 Show[
  ListCurvePathPlot[p3, Mesh -> All, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[ColorData[97][2], PointSize[Large]], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"Number of points: ", Length@p3, " out of ", n}]],
  ListPlot[p3, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.01]}]],
 {{minDistance3, .02}, 0.01, 0.05}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just noticed @Rom38 essentially mentioned the same approach in the comments above, credit goes to them.

This can be solved as two separate questions: namely separating the points into 'curves' and then down-sampling a list of points.

For the first question, I use [`FindShortestTour`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindShortestTour.html) to find a single continuous curve, and then split it up according to EuclideanDistance jumps. I suspect this might need some fine-tuning for different use-cases, but seems to work well for the case of OP:

```
data = Flatten[{Table[{x, Sin[x^2/15]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.01}],Table[{x, 2 + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.1}]}, 1];
pts = RandomSample[data];

tour = Last[FindShortestTour[pts]];
tourPts = Extract[pts, List /@ tour];
peaks = Ordering[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[tourPts, 2, 1], -2];
{firstCurve, secondCurve} = TakeDrop[RotateLeft[tourPts, peaks[[1]]], Abs[Subtract @@ peaks]];
```

For the second question, there's many related questions on this site, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/equidistant-points-on-a-polyline) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve). I'll use the accepted solution from the first link for demonstration purposes.

```
np[f_][u_, dt_] := u + dt/Norm[f'[u]]
equallySpacedPts[pts_, dt_] := With[{bsf = BSplineFunction[pts]},
  bsf /@ Most[NestWhileList[np[bsf][#, dt] &, 0, # < 1 &]]]

equallySpacedPts[#, 0.25] & /@ {firstCurve, secondCurve} // ListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I had changed your `pts` definition as follows `pts = RandomSample[data]` to avoid duplicates and forgot to include in answer above. Note that if you want to only use some of the data, you can use something like `pts = RandomSample[data, Floor[Length[data] 0.5]]` for a duplicate-free random list of half the points.

Comment: Thank you again .Would the method work with an unknown number of curves?   Or a known one  but not necessarily 2?

Comment: The first part would need to be generalized slightly to identify multiple curves using `EuclideanDistance` jumps, but as long as `FindShortestTour` finds a reasonable path (e.g. the curves don't intersect), I reckon it should be easy to do.